# How to introduce a loss to get two matrices similar

Tags: python, matrix, statistics, pytorch, linear-algebra

I am training a neural network and I want two matrices to be similar (the covariance matrices). My naive approach was to use a loss based on the difference, such as the L1 loss. But this also forced the matrices to become small, which is not what I want.

Does anyone have an idea here?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How do you define two matrices being close to each other?

Comment: The covariance matrices are used to define 2d distributions. Therefore, the two matrices are more similar to each other the more the sampled distributions are similar.

Comment: "The covariance matrices are used to define 2d distributions" wouldn't be so sure about that. But my question was: how do you measure similarity between your two matrices: is it element-wise?

Comment: I am referring to my case, I use the covariance matrices to sample from a multivariate distribution, that's based on the mean and the covariance. Yes, for my naive approach I used element-wise difference. But this forced the covariance matrices to be small. I am looking for something like the cosine similarity, that is more invariant to the "magnitude" of the matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many metrics you can use (euclidian distances, cosine similarity, the Bhattacharyya similarity for non-negative features, the Jensen-Shannon divergence).

The cosine similarity seems like a good place to start. You can achieve this by considering both `n x m` matrices in a `n*m` dimensional space. And, compare those two vectors with the cosine similarity.

In practice, this can be done using [`torch.flatten`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.flatten.html#torch-flatten) and [`torch.nn.functionnal.cosine_similarity`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#torch.nn.functional.cosine_similarity). Or equivalently with a [`nn.Flatten`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Flatten.html) layer and [`nn.CosineSimilarity`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CosineSimilarity.html).

Here I've taken the functional route:

```
>>> x = torch.rand(1, 10, 10)
>>> y = torch.rand(1, 10, 10)

>>> F.cosine_similarity(torch.flatten(x, 1), torch.flatten(y, 1))
tensor([0.6220])
```

Notice you will need an extra dimension for the batch: `axis=0`.

---

*Edit* - if you're not working with batches, you could simply broadcast both tensors to 1D tensors:

```
>>> F.cosine_similarity(x.reshape(1, -1), y.reshape(1, -1))
```